# How to send a command to a FFmpeg `color` source filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

[FFmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Commands-151) states:

> The `color` source supports the following commands:
>
> `c, color` - the `color` source filter

How can I use this command?

Thinking a standard `sendcmd` usage, I tried

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sendcmd='1 color c blue',color=c=red output.mp4
```

I got slapped by

```
[lavfi @ 000001f4fefcbd80] Too many inputs specified for the "color" filter.
sendcmd=1 color c blue,color=c=red: Invalid argument
```

which makes sense because `color` filter does not take any input stream.

Is there some other way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place sendcmd afterwards.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=c=red,sendcmd='1 color c blue'" output.mp4
```

Command processing filters like sendcmd or zmq can be anywhere in the filtergraph. But they should remain alive for the duration of the lifetime of command recipients. A filter "dies" if its feeding filter hits EOF. So, `some_filter,trim=end_frame=1,sendcmd` will be dead very quickly.

Comment: Ah huh. I had this presumption that a command flows with the frames till it hits the first match. So, is this the reason for the `filter_name@id` syntax to specify which instance of a filter to apply the command when there are multiple instances in the filtergraph?